What exactly is component-based architecture and how do I get it to work?
My problems with OOP:
For a while now, I have been attempting to make full games on Godot, but I keep running into issues around poor organization and planning with my classes and OOP architecture. After days of working on a project, I would run into a devastating issue with the way I organized my class hierarchy, resulting in me having to restart or give up on the project to not waste time to go through and fix every class in the class hierarchy. I recently have started to be way too timid to get anything done with my project, fearing that one mistake in my organization could cause me to restart again.
What I think the functionality of Component-based architecture is:
When I came across component-based architecture, I thought I could be able to make a base class and then integrate component classes that serve separate functionalities to the base class, so I wouldn't have to make large class hierarchies and better manage and organize my code.
Why I need help with implementing component-based architecture:
While trying to implement a component-based design, I found that I had no idea how to exactly make one work at all. I don't understand how I could integrate the functionality of one class into another without having prebuilt code that is made directly for each possible component, which beats the purpose of component-based architecture. I don't know how I get the base class to properly run component code without directly and consciously addressing each type of component. I keep trying to do research on my own, but I just end up getting more confused as I try to look it up.
This is how I have it setting up my component based system in pseudocode:
class EventPayload {

    eventType = "Type Name"

    payload = Empty Dictionary //Stores payload data
}

class Component {

    owner = Null Object

    name = "Component Name"

    dependentComponents = Array

    messageEvent(eventPayload = EventPayload) {

        switch eventPayload.eventType{

            "Something" {
                //does something

            }
        }
    }
}

Final Thoughts
Thanks to your help I got a system working where I can attach Component classes to a host class and managed to get them to communicate with each other and to other components via the host using the "EventMessage"-ing system that I made.

You may be interested in the principle of Composition Over Inheritance, which describes the cognitive realignment from thinking in terms of the type an object "is" (where all that code lives in a rigid inheritance hierarchy) to what behaviours it "has" (in components that can be mixed and matched). We have some past Q&A showcasing this in various scenarios that might help you build some familiarity.

One thing that I found out and understood in the search of other similar post was that I need some sort of update function in the "base" class that messages the all of its components. So like if I had a board game class, I could have a character input function that tells what the character did in the game and it would send a message to all the components that a character did something with the board game and capatible components to the action such as a chess component or a remise component would respond with a functionality. But I would still like some more understanding on the subject.

Try ditching OOP and a sensible method instead - https://betterprogramming.pub/object-oriented-programming-the-trillion-dollar-disaster-92a4b666c7c7

Don't force your code to fit OOD patterns. If your code happens to fit OOD, that is good. If your code does not fit any OOD patterns, then just write your code as it is. The main thing is to get your game work well while writing good code.

If it provides any insight, VB6 (vs VB.NET) was component based. No OOP. All drag and drop. Components are objects that are attached to other objects. The challenge is deciding what makes a worthy component, and how to interact with it. For animating my objects, for example, the actual script for each animated object is in a dictionary; versus adding an animation reference to the object. The object  "asks" the dictionary: "Am I animating?" (for example)

@Engineer I understand the concept now and how I could get it to work but I could use any new info i could get to better my programming knowledge.

I have been using oop to make different components and sub components such as Component << WeaponStatsComponent << RubberDuckSwordStatsComponent. Where WeaponStats i could give it to an item host class and a RubberDuckSwords stats I could easily load up and give it to host class if the weapon is defined. This is not what I'm making for my project but It gets the idea of what I'm doing across.

@BrighamPeterson I've started a series of tutorials (2 available so far) that may help you with this, since these kinds of questions about ECS are frequently asked. Specifically helps you see ECS in the context of no OOP, classes, interfaces, or traits (C style). It is a lengthy topic and the Q&A format here doesn't suit a fuller explanation of the architecture.

@BrighamPeterson I've started a series of tutorials (3 so far) (codementor, github) that may help your implementation. Helps you see ECS in the context of no OOP inheritance hierarchies, a pure C-like ECS. It is a lengthy topic and the Q&A format here doesn't suit a fuller explanation of the architecture.

What are Components?
Consider the following two (partial) classes:
public partial class Composition
{
    private List<Component> Components;

    public TComponent? GetComponent<TComponent>() where TComponent : Component
    {
        return this.Components.OfType<TComponent>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void DispatchEvent<TEventArgs>(TEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        foreach(var component in this.Components)
        {
            component.ReceiveEvent(eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Component
{
    public Composition Owner { get; }

    public abstract void ReceiveEvent<TEventArgs>(TEventArgs eventArgs);
}

A composition contains zero or more components. Anyone with a handle to the composition can do two things:

Get a specific component, if they know the component's type
Send an event to all components.

Similarly, a Component can do two things:

Access its owner
Receive an event

These two snippets, taken together, create a minimal Component Based System. Each game object is a composition of game object components, and the Game (which can itself be a composition of different systems) knows about the list of game objects.
How do you use Components?
In this simplified example: When a global event happens (for example PhysicsUpdateEvent which happens a fixed number of times per second), the game dispatches that event to each game object, which in turn dispatches it to each of their components to handle.
There is no rule saying that components cannot know about other components - for example, a RigidBodyComponent has to know about the TransformComponent so that it can update the position and rotation to apply the events of velocity and angular velocity during each PhysicsUpdateEvent.
The idea is that components only need to handle the event in front of them, then return control to the game.
(In the real world, you would probably want to write a more efficient event handling system such that components only receive the events that are interesting to them.)
Why Components
The primary advantages of a component based system are:

You can pick and choose what features each game object has. For example, in an inheritance-based system, Shopkeeper might be a subclass of NPC, which would cause problems if you want to have something that isn't an NPC act as a shop (such as a statue). In a component based system, you could stick the Shop component on any object.
Components only need to know about other components that are relevant to them. Physics needs to know about position, but it doesn't need to know about Sound. If collisions make a noise, that can be handled by the Collision system dispatching a CollisionImpactEvent and some other system listening for that event and playing the appropriate sound.


Practical Example
Imagine a simplified Minecraft-like game. There is a world full of voxels. Right away, we have three kinds of object:

Mobile (like players, zombies, and cows)
Part of the voxel map (like crafting tables and treasure chests)
Inventory items (like armor and tools)

In an inheritance-based system, you might create three a base class for each of these three kinds of objects, and then subclass those for individual behaviors - for example, Chest inherits from VoxelObject, which inherits from GameObject. Then maybe you have a few special objects which inherit from GameObjects directly (to handle global things like the Day/Night cycle, mob spawning, etc.)
However, a few days later, you want to add the Horadric Cube from Diablo (or maybe just a Bag of Holding) into your game - so you need the Inventory behavior of a Chest, but now it needs to be on an InventoryItemObject instead. In an inheritance-based system, what follows would be either a nasty refactor or code duplication, to make the inventory functionality of Chest available to a class that derives from InventoryItemObject.
With components, it's much simpler: Every game object is a composite. Aside from the special objects mentioned above, each of those objects has either the InventoryItemObject, VoxelObject or MobileObject component - but if you need to make a container that's an InventoryItemObject instead of a VoxelObject, you can simply instantiate a new composition with the right components even at runtime, without compiling any new code.
Can I add functionality to the Composition?
Yes, absolutely. If in your game, every object has a Position (for example), then it might be more convenient (and less error-prone) to have that be a property of the Composition itself, rather than on a component which everything needs to have an instance of.

I'm confused with the composition class. Is it the host class such as a character or a tile/voxel in a sand box game that stores and uses components?

Yes. This Composition class can play the role of what we might call an "entity" or "game object". Each entity/game object can have a collection of components associated with it (they can be stored in a list as shown here, though other arrangements are also possible). I suspect Tim C called it "Composition" instead of "entity/game object" to emphasize that it can also be used for more abstract collections of behaviour, like the game rules themselves, that don't necessarily map to a "thing" with a physical/visual presence in the game world.

@BrighamPeterson - Every game object that has its own logic is a composition, but I wouldn't necessarily go as far as to make every tile a composition. Instead, you might have a TileMap component on one composition which handles all the normal tiles/voxels, and then have additional compositions for tiles that have logic (like chests or crafting tables) with a component like TileMapActor that places them in the grid, and have the TileMapActors know about the TileMap which they're associated with.

The important thing is that other logic (like item containers) doesn't inherit from TileMapActor - it just sits in the same composition as a TileMapActor component, and if it needs to get its position in the tile map for some reason, it can call this.Owner.GetComponent<TileMapActor>().

I've added a practical example explaining some of the above to the answer.

I want to address the following section in the original post:

I would run into a devastating issue with the way I organized my class hierarchy, resulting in me having to restart or give up on the project to not waste time to go through and fix every class in the class hierarchy. I recently have started to be way too timid to get anything done with my project, fearing that one mistake in my organization could cause me to restart again.

We all make mistakes, having to go back and rework stuff is a natural part of the development of any software.
However there are techniques/skills which can make it less painful.
Separation of Concerns
Components are one way to separate concerns, what this means is that we try to divide up our code base so that major pieces such as:

Graphics.
Audio
AI.
Menus
Score/Stats
...

Are separate from each other. The reason we do this is that when we make a mistake in one area it limits the amount of code we have to rework / search through in order to make a change.
As a starting point I would suggest don't worry too much about the "perfect" pattern just try to break things up, so that similar functionality is grouped together.
Source Control
It is extremely frustrating to realize that a change you made broke a bunch of stuff and it can be paralyzing when you don't know exactly where you broke it. You don't want to make future changes for fear that you will break something else.
It's worth investing some time to learn a source control tool, so that you can have confidence that you can make a change and roll back if things go badly.
I think Git is a good choice - but your milage may vary.
Refactoring
Godot's default editor is very weak with respect to tools for refactoring.
I have started using the GDScript plugin for the JetBrains IDE's. The plugin itself is free, but I am not sure which if any of the free JetBrains IDE's are compatible with the plugin (I have a paid JetBrains subscription).
The only refactoring tool that the plugin provides is a context sensitive rename (it will rename a method or variable based on usage data). However I find this one feature is useful enough to switch to a different IDE when I need to do significant refactoring.
My point here is two fold:

Firstly improving your refactoring skills (with or without tooling support) will make thing far less frustrating (you don't have to give up and start again).
You might want to look into additional tooling to help with refactoring (I have used JetBrains for years so it works for me - something else may work better for you).

